# Problems retrieving Test Configurations from MTM 2013 test context

Tags: c#, visual-studio, selenium, automated-tests, microsoft-test-manager

When I execute my test from MTM, `context.Properties.Contains("__Tfs_TestConfigurationName__")` always returns `false`. When I am in the Run Tests tab in MTM, the test case displays "Default Run on Firefox" under configuration. Is there an additional step I need to take for the `__Tfs_TestConfigurationName__` key to appear in the context dictionary?

MTM About Dialog Info: VS/MTM: 2013; Version: 12.0.31101.0

I have already read the Marcel de Vries article, which is where I got the `__Tfs_TestConfigurationName__` key from.  [Switching browser in CodedUI or Selenium tests based on MTM configuration](http://fluentbytes.com/switching-browser-in-codedui-or-selenium-tests-based-on-mtm-configuration/#comment-177961). However, that method doesn't appear to be working for me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found an answer on MSDN [here](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/259a5e23-d99f-4f61-a7a9-f7d1084356ce/using-mtm-2013-test-configuration-names-in-selenium-tests?forum=vsmantest).